# Excel VBA Autofill not populating first row and column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a formula from one cell into a block of cells.  I have tried using AutoFill, which works to a degree, but it does not populate the first row or the first column.

My formula in C4 should be copied to the entire block C4:X12.  (In real life it is a sumproduct.)

```
Sub GetUniqueLocationsTEST()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    With thisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range("C4").formula = "=1+1"
        .Range("C4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C4:X12") ', .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    End With
End Sub
```

Results in C4 showing "2", and the range D5:X12 correctly showing "2".
BUT D4:X4 and C5:C12 are blank - nothing is copied there!  If I put other random text into these cells it is still there after the Sub is run.

In the sample code you'll see that I've even forced the destination range to a literal.

Perhaps Autofill is not the correct method?  Should I be using Copy?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need `AutoFill`. You can write a formula to an entire range in one go, and Excel will update relative references if needed:

```
.Range("C4", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Formula = your formula
```

Comment: Beat me to it; was always going to add that the use of fixed and dynamic references in your formula *will* be carried forward, e.g., "B$2" will iterate input over a range of columns while the row will not change when inputting over a range of rows.